# Should I shuffle the list before quicksort in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

It is suggested that we shuffle the array before quicksort it.

However, if we want to quicksort a list, shuffling list first will take `O(nlogn)`, for example, we assign a random key to each item in the list and then mergesort the (key, item) list.

Then **my question** is:

If we have to spend `O(nlogn)` to shuffle the list first, then what's the point of implementing quicksort for list in OCaml?

We should just use mergesort directly, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OP's question:

> However, if we want to quicksort a list, shuffling list first will
>   take O(nlogn)

I think a random shuffling costs only `O(n)` time if you first convert the list into an array and then use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is also the algorithm used in Python's random.shuffle.

Comment: Well, make some benchmark and then show results. In theory you are right in practice well implemented merge sort will beat you.

Comment: I like the `convert list to array, then shuffle array, then convert back` idea

Comment: @JacksonTale Trust me, I have implemented all reasonable sorting algorithms including exotic ones. I have implemented many of them in various programming languages including exotic and esoteric ones. I'm implementing very specialized super fast sorting algorithms in real applications for living. First, shuffling array will kill cache coherency and increase constant at same start of work. Second, quick sort is NlogN in average and N^2 in worst case. Shuffling minimize probability of this worst case but there still be there probability to be worse than NlogN. Merge sort is NlogN in worst case.

Answer (score 2):

I would use mergesort as you suggest. Mergesort even fits in functional language better than quicksort.